# Using batch queries in typescript with cassandra , inserting only one row in table in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0

**Using this way**

const client = new cassandra.Client({
contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'],
localDataCenter: 'eu-west-3',
keyspace: 'test',

### });

```js
const query1 = 'INSERT INTO user_track (key, text, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
const query2 = 'INSERT INTO user_track (key, text, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
const queries = [
   { query: query1, params: ['hendrix1', 'Changed email1', new Date()]},
   { query: query2, params: ['hendrix2', 'Changed email2', new Date()] } 
];
// Promise-based call
client.batch(queries, { prepare: true })
  .then(function() {
    // All queries have been executed successfully
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // None of the changes have been applied
  });
```

***Inserting only one row..***

My expectation is to insert all rows.

Comment: You were expecting two rows to be inserted?

Comment: Can you describe the table schema?

Comment: At what consistency level are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm curious to know what your underlying table `user_track` looks like.

Based on what you described, I did a `npm install cassandra-driver`, started Cassandra locally, and created my `user_track` table like this, with `key` as my `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE user_track (
    key TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    text TEXT,
    date DATE);
```

I then ran your code, and I have two rows:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm user_track ;

 key      | date       | text
----------+------------+----------------
 hendrix1 | 2023-04-10 | Changed email1
 hendrix2 | 2023-04-10 | Changed email2

(2 rows)
```

Here's my Git repo, if you'd like to have a look: https://github.com/aar0np/nodejsCassandraTest/tree/main

So everything looks correct from a code standpoint.  Maybe reverify that you're on the latest version of the Nodejs cassandra-driver?